# Exchange 2010 - branch office sending large emails "locally" but server is at HQ

Tags: exchange-2010

I've had an issue lately where one of our branch offices with around 60 employees will end up sending a 10MB email to 20 users at that facility.

The problem is that the email server itself is located at HQ across a 1.5Mbps MPLS circuit.

So what happens is the Exchange server at HQ has to send a 10MB email to 20 different users across that pipe to their cached OST file (unless I'm missing something, but that's what it appears to do on the network).

This causes serious congestion on that link until all of that traffic is transmitted.

Besides putting a mailbox server at the branch office or limiting email size, are there other ways to mitigate this?

Comment: Use sharepoint for file storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your four options are:

1. Increase bandwidth
2. Limit attachment size
3. Put an Exchange server at the remote site, configure a mailstore on it, and then house those users locally to that mailstore.  If you try to do direct replication with your primary mailbox server, you'll crush the pipe in a similar fashion.
4. Put a fileserver at that location and explain to users that email is not a fileshare.  Seriously - if they're all local to that office, why are they emailing documents? It's an inefficient use of Exchange storage space.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, create a Transport Rule that only allows the sending of large messages until approved by a moderator, which can be done outside of office hours.